# disable coolapse mode of layout inside appbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout

i have a framelayout inside a appbar i want to disable collapse mode of framelayout when the appbar collapse in .i can't move the framelayout outside the appbar because i have a detail fragment outside the appbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/act_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags=“scroll|enterAlways"/>


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33496348/5154891) ?

Comment: thnx but i don't want the layout inside the appbar to colapse i want it fix